# Change NSTexfield focus by pressing Enter key

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield

In my OS X App, how can I change the `NSTextField` focus by pressing the Enter key instead of pressing the Tab key?

Comment: What u want to do? Tab key switch focus to the next control by default in OS X and Enter - end editing.

Comment: I want press ENTER key to end editing and switch focus to the next control simultaneously. Is it Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `NSText` `- (void)textDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification` delegate method, where you should use `NSWindow`’s `makeFirstResponder`: to change the current first responder. See the [NSResponder class reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for details on this.

First set `delegate` of your firs textField to `self`. Then in same class:

```
- (void)textDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
     NSLog(@"delegate method");
    [self.window makeFirstResponder:[[[aNotification object]window]nextResponder]];
}
```

I assume that you do this in AppDelegate class.

Comment: I tried to use this method:

- (IBAction)changeFocus:(id)sender
{
    NSResponder*resp=[sender nextResponder];
    [myWindow makeFirstResponder:resp];
   
}

and link this action to my Textfield press ENTER key, but it doesn't work - 
??

Comment: Are u shure the method will invoke?

Comment: yes I'm sure, it seems that the [sender nextResponder] does not work

Comment: Try to NSLog your "resp" NSLog(@"next resp = %@",resp);

Comment: The response of NSLog is: <NSView: 0x1005d97f0> - how do I see which control is?

Comment: @user3313512 Add a user identifier to the control.

Comment: I realized that when invoke [sender nextResponder] -(sender is my NSTextfield)- the nextResponder is the NSView that contain all my textfield. At runtime instead when I press TAB key the focus change from one Textfield to another- suggestions? thx